# Create a new Android PhoneGap project either via the command line tools

Tags: java, android, cordova, ant, command-line

I am developing Android Application using jQuery Mobile and Phonegap and as I mention in the question I need to open Android project through Command Line, I set 3 path in my Environmental Variable.

1. ANT_HOME (C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4-bin\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin)
2. JAVA_HOME (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07)
3. PATH (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin)

I download the latest version of Phonegap, then in command line i give path to phonegap folder.

```
cd C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\phonegap\phonegap-2.9.1\phonegap-2.9.1\lib\android\bin
```

It's working good then I type

```
create (path of folder to create App)com.example.project DemoApp
```

output is:

```
Cannot not locate ant.bat using the PATH variable.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the ANT_HOME to the PATH variable.

Open the console window and type the following

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANT_HOME%
```

or You could do it by changing the PATH environment variable in the window below.

```
MyComputer->Properties->Advanced->Env Variables->Path.
```

EDIT1:
Check the following links for installing cordova/phonegap.

http://thejackalofjavascript.com/phonegap-3-cli-setup-mac-windows/

http://coenraets.org/blog/cordova-phonegap-3-tutorial/

http://teusink.blogspot.in/2013/07/guide-phonegap-3-android-windows.html

Comment: SORRY, but i am not getting you.
i have already another path for PATH variable.

Comment: i try this:
ANT_HOME (C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4-bin\apache-ant-1.9.4)
PATH (C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4-bin\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin)
but it show
cannot locate javac.exe using PATH environment variable.

Comment: You should NOT replace the PATH variable. You need to APPEND/ADD at the end of the PATH variable. your PATH variable should be `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4-bin\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin`

Comment: yeah i add the ANT_HOME path in PATH variable using ;(semicolon)along with Java but now it gives me cannot locate android.bat using PATH variable.

Comment: ya i have found that cscript.exe in that path.. i had deleted the environment variable for
c:\windows\system32 by mistake.. so oly that error was occured..  now i fixed that error..

Comment: @user3603107 if the answer has solved your question. Please accept the answer